# Coq: prove that an inductive type w/o a non-recursive constructor is uninhabitated

Tags: coq, dependent-type, theorem-proving

I'm new to Coq an its underlying theory. Suppose there is an inductive type which have no non-recursive constructors. It's impossible to produce an instance of it. But could it be proven?

```
Inductive impossible : Type :=
  | mk (x : impossible).

Theorem indeed_impossible : forall (x : impossible), False.
```

If no - is it a drawback of Coq or a feature of CoC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily proved by induction on `x`. You only get an inductive step with an absurd induction hypothesis, and no base case which would require you to actually produce an absurdity.

```
Theorem indeed_impossible : forall (x : impossible), False.
Proof.
  induction 1.
  (* just need to show [False |- False] *)
  trivial.
Qed.
```

Edit by: @simpadjo:
Alternative proof which is more clear for me personally:

```
Theorem indeed_impossible : forall (x : impossible), False.
Proof.
 intros. induction x. assumption. Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to apply inversion and it of course got me nowhere.

Comment: @HTNW thank you for providing the proof script. I proved it a bit differently (see my edits). Could you please explain what does `induction 1` mean?

Comment: Hm, my edit is not yet visible because it requires peer review. Here is the proof:
intros. induction x. assumption. Qed.

Comment: @simpadjo `induction 1` is the same as `intros x. induction x` with a fresh name `x`. `trivial` is a variant of `auto`, except it tries even less to solve the goal. `auto` always checks for assumptions first. [Here's the documentation.](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html)

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, you can just say `now induction 1`.